# How can I make my phone prefer my mobile network (LTE) over WiFi?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, cellular-data

I have an iPhone 7. Is there a way that I can make it prefer my mobile network over WiFi? This is because I'll be traveling on a ferry and want it to use the much cheaper mobile network over the exorbitant prices charged by the ferry's operator. This is mainly for when I get back in range of cellular - I'll manually switch at the beginning of the journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the WiFi on the ferry is not free, it would most probably ask you to login before using it. Then, if you do not login to it, your iPhone should continue using the cellular network instead of the ferry’s WiFi. To ensure this works as planned, make sure “Ask To Join Networks” in Settings->WiFi on your iPhone is turned on.

If for some reason your iPhone has been connected to the WiFi on the ferry before, it might remember that and reconnect to the WiFi automatically on the ferry. To prevent this, go to Settings->WiFi before starting your journey, find the name of the Wifi on the ferry, tap on the info button next to it and tap on “Forget This Network”.

The two above should be enough to make your iPhone use the cellular network instead of the ferry's WiFi. In case you wish to take extra action or do it differently, here is what you can also do:

You can prevent your iPhone connecting to any WiFi network through its control center for the next 24 hours: shortly before boarding the ferry, swipe up from the bottom of your iPhone (swipe down from the top right for iPhone X or later)  to open its control center and tap on the WiFi icon so that its color changes from blue to white. Assuming you will be on the ferry for less than 24 hours, you can change this back after you leave the ferry through the same procedure.

Another solution is to turn off the WiFi on your iPhone completely through Settings->WiFi, either shortly before boarding the ferry or at the beginning of your journey, and turn it on through the same procedure after leaving the ferry.

Comment: Minor point; iPhone 7 is Touch ID, so swipe up from the bottom, not down from top right.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to make it change automatically - but I suspect this isn't an option. Thanks for the info